# My getView Method is not being called in my Array Adapter

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm new to Android development and I'm stuck at the moment because my getView method in my custom adapter is not being called. I'm trying to display data I'm collecting from an API, parse it, and render it onto a screen in android studio. Please help!

Here's My Fargment:

```
public class eventsFragment extends Fragment {
View myView;
View rootView;
ArrayList<events> eventList;
private ListView LV;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String url = "https://kambuku.com/app/tickets";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, container, false);
    eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    LV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.List);

    //GET CONNECTION INFO
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, container, false);
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new getAllEvents().execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "No Active Connection!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    return myView;

}


private class getAllEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String feed = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Show Progress Dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait... Fetching your Events");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String Result;
        String DEBUG_TAG = "EVENTS";

        HttpHandler handle = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = null;
        try {
            jsonStr = handle.EventsConnection(url, DEBUG_TAG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Result = jsonStr;

        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "JSON RESPONSE IS" + Result);
        if (Result != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Result);
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "JSON OBJECT IS" + jsonObject);

                //GET JSON ARRAY NODE
                JSONArray tickets = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tickets");
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "JSON TICKET ARRAY LENGTH IS" + tickets.length());

                for (int i = 0; i < tickets.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject t = tickets.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "JSON OBJECT " + i + " is " + t);


                    events event = new events();

                    event.setEventName(t.getString("eventName"));
                    event.setId(t.getString("id"));
                    event.setVenue(t.getString("venue"));
                    event.setCity(t.getString("city"));
                    event.setArtwork("https://kambuku.com/"+t.getString("artwork"));
                    event.setHost(t.getString("host"));
                    event.setNotes(t.getString("notes"));
                    event.setPrice(t.getString("price"));
                    event.setEventDate(t.getString("eventDate"));


                    eventList.add(event);
                }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("PostExecute", "YOUR LIST ARE "+eventList);
        eventsAdapter eventAdapter = new eventsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.event_item, eventList);
        LV.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

}

Here's My Adapter:

```
public class eventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private ArrayList<events> ArrayListEvents;
private int Resource;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public eventsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<events> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    Log.e("ADAPTER", "OBJECTS ARE "+objects);
    Log.e("ADAPTER", "RESOURCES ARE "+resource);

    ArrayListEvents = objects;
    Resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("ADAPTER", "WE ARE HERE");
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.artwork = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Artwork);
        holder.eventName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        holder.eventNotes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventNotes);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (eventsAdapter.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    new DownloadImageResource(holder.artwork).execute(ArrayListEvents.get(position).getArtwork());
    holder.eventName.setText(ArrayListEvents.get(position).getEventName());
    holder.eventNotes.setText(ArrayListEvents.get(position).getNotes());
    Log.e("Holder", "Holder"+holder.eventName.getText());
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView artwork;
    TextView eventName;
    TextView eventNotes;
}


private class DownloadImageResource extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    ImageView Artwork;

    DownloadImageResource(ImageView Artwork)
    {
        this.Artwork = Artwork;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String urlDisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap conn = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            conn = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        Log.e("Image", "Image Download"+result);
        Artwork.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the listview after setting its adapter

Comment: LV.notifyDataSetChanged(); call this after calling adapter

Comment: You should never call AsyncTask inside getView method().

Comment: Just tried that, Its not helping. @Kilanny

Answer (score 0):

Override getItemCount method in your adapter.

@Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return ArrayListEvents .size();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are executing nested AsyncTask. I.e. you are running another task for each row in the listview, which is already running a task. This is not good in Android. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498001/android-asynctask-inside-asynctask) for more details.